# Airflow not importing the DAG file

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I have a DAG folder of 13 DAGs. All of them show up in the UI except one which shows an DAG import timeout error after 30s. We increased it to 3600s to see how much time it actually takes as even updating it to 90 seconds did not help.

Below is what I see in the `dag_processor_manager.log` file (Issue is with the first file):

```
================================================================================
[2023-01-17T18:17:37.779+0000] INFO - {manager.py:828} 
================================================================================
DAG File Processing Stats

File Path                                                                  PID  Runtime      # DAGs    # Errors  Last Runtime    Last Run
-----------------------------------------------------------------------  -----  ---------  --------  ----------  --------------  -------------------
/opt/airflow/dags/SourceGroup_1_DAG.py        25391  3281.28s          0           0
/opt/airflow/dags/dag_generator_trigger.py                                                1           0  0.97s           2023-01-17T18:14:10
```

We are not able to figure out what is causing the DAG import to take so much time! The same DAG is running fine in our development environment.

Comment: Without showing code, we'd have to guess what your code looks like... If your DAG file imports fast on another system it's likely due to an external dependency. You could try to isolate the problem by removing lines of code until you figure out which line makes a difference.

Comment: One potential issue could be [top-level DAG code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code)